# How to solve high request latency on Cloud Run (nearly 4minutes)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Hi everyone at this point I am at a loss. I am in the process of brining our application up in Cloud Run. I did have a little bit of worry running "serverless" for this application stack. I have 1 frontend NextJS application and Backend GraphQL (node) application. I use schema stitching against the backend to connect to our managed CMS service.

I bumped the number of max instances the Serverless VPC access connector and this really helped the requests from 5/6 slowdown to 1/6.

Right now, 1/6 requests are being very slow (nearly 4minutes to resolve). The slow request is when the browser asks for the API to return information from the CMS + some information on the CMS data from our internal DB. I have this same application running in heroku with less resources and it is running smooth so to me that rules out a code issue.

Areas I have checked:

- Cloud SQL CPU and connection pool (very low)
- Container Image size (small as a node app can be)
- Keeping min and max number of containers at the same number
- Allocating CPU

I am at the point of thinking the backend application is just not a proper fit for Cloud Run but I do like the simplicity of getting applications running in cloud run and their approach to serverless.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Cloud Run integrates with Cloud SQL very well. To debug a problem like this you must find where the problem is occurring. Use logging and time functions to narrow down your code to the actual problem path. Then post that code with more details in your question.

Comment: Cloud Run runs container. If you have slowness, there is a bootleneck somewhere. Normally, if you run your container on a COmpute Engine, with 1 CPU (or the same number of CPU) and you should have the same issue.